# How can I move the weather icon next to the weather condition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My icon is hanging low at the left corner of the screen. I'd love to know the >fastest way to place it next to the weather condition (right below Your >Location).

Link  to [Codepen](https://codepen.io/cmtran/pen/POwXyZ)

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class=" text-center"> Your Local Current Weather</h1> <br>
  <div>
    <h2 id="location" class="text-center"> </h2>
    <h2 id="condition" class="text-center">
    </h2>

    <h2 class="text-center" style="cursor: pointer">Temperature: <span id="temperature" class="toggle"></span></h2>
    <canvas id="icon" width="100" height="100"></canvas>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this work if I don't allow codepen access to my location?

Comment: I don't see an icon or 'your location'.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1):

Place Canvas tag right after Your Local Current Weather :

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1 class= " text-center"> Your Local Current Weather</h1> <br>
    <canvas id="icon" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
  <div>
  <h2 id = "location" class = "text-center"> </h2>
  <h2 id= "condition" class="text-center">
     </h2>

  <h2 class="text-center" style="cursor: pointer">Temperature: <span id="temperature" class="toggle"></span></h2> 

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

and add this in CSS:

```
#icon {
 position: relative;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10%)
}
```

I have updated it [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WXbBqa)